# No compilation errors but not getting any output in C

Tags: c, function, output

This has been bugging me a lot. It is a simple function to detect a prime number but I'm not getting any output on my console, despite there being no compilation errors. Can someone please detect what is wrong with this code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int isprime(int);

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (isprime(n))
        printf("Yes");
    else
        printf("No");

    return 0;
}

int isprime(int num)
{
    int flag = 1;

    for(int i = 2; i <= num/2; i++)
    {
        if(num % i == 0)
        {
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Comment: How did you run the program? What input did you provide? Note that you program starts by requiring some user input without printing any prompt beforehand.

Comment: Your output does not contain a newline.  If your PS1 moves the cursor to beginning of line, then your prompt very likely overwrites the output.

Comment: It works for me. Note that since you didn't end your `printf` with a newline, the output will be on same line as your next shell prompt, so you might not see it.

Comment: It seems you are having problems understanding the behavior of the program. As mentioned by @uneven_mark, we need to know how you are running the program (e.g., what command you use to run the program, what input are you providing to the program) to gain more understanding into what behavior you are encountering. And, it might also matter what your environment is (operating system, and compiler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the program. The output is not formatted well due to missing new lines, so perhaps by adding them you'd be able to see something as the output may be right at the beginning of the console prompt.

```
int n;
printf("Input a number: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

if (isprime(n))
    printf("Yes\n");
else
    printf("No\n");
```

Comment: Yeah, it was a noob move. Thanks for the clarification though!

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function `isprime` is invalid. It returns `1` for the non-prime number `1`.:)

And the function should be declared at least like

```
int isprime( unsigned int num );
```

As for your question then the output buffer is not flushed until the new line character is not encountered.

Write instead

```
if (isprime(n))
    printf("Yes\n");
else
    printf("No\n");
```

or

```
if (isprime(n))
    puts("Yes");
else
    puts("No");
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you don't see the output but it is shown. There is no new line and command prompt follows the answer like `NoC:\>` instead of `C:\>`.